# PowerShell HashTable - self referencing during initialization

Tags: powershell, initialization, hashtable

I have a theoretical problem - how to reference a hash table during its initialization, for example, to compute a member based other already stated members.

```
Remove-Variable myHashTable -ErrorAction Ignore
$myHashTable = 
@{
    One = 1
    Two= 2
    Three = ??? # following expressions do not work 
        # $This.One + $This.Two or 
        # $_.One + $_.Two
        # $myHashTable.One + $myHashTable.Two
        # ????
}

$myHashTable.Three -eq 3 # make this $true
```

Any ideas how to do it? Is it actually possible?

Edit: 
This was my solution:

```
$myHashTable = 
@{
    One = 1
    Two= 2
}
$myHashTable.Three = $myHashTable.One + $myHashTable.Two
```

Comment: yep... that was my solution too... bu t I hoped there was a $self.key ... or $this.key ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also recur to this...
sometimes when the hashtable is very long
and can be defined only in 2 or three recurrences...
works fine:

```
$AAA = @{
    DAT = "C:\MyFolderOfDats"
    EXE = "C:\MyFolderOfExes"
    }

$AAA += @{
    Data   = $AAA.DAT + "\#Links"

    Scripts  = $AAA.EXE + "\#Scripts"
    ScriptsX = $AAA.EXE + "\#ScriptsX"
    }
```

> - Note in the second part we are just adding ( += )
>    more items to the first part...
>    but now... we can refer the items
>    in first part
>     of the hashtable

Comment: This does not answer the original question `how to reference a hash table during its initialization`.  I do not understand how it's possible my answer was "unaccepted" and losing 15 rep, when this one - while being potentially useful in a different context - is actually wrong.

Answer (score 8):

This won't be possible using the object initializer syntax I'm afraid.  While it is possible to use variables, you'll have to compute the values before creating the object.

Comment: This answer has been looming ahead :-(.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot recommend this, but you can iterate the initializer twice or more:

```
(0..1) | %{
    $a = @{
        One = 1
        Two = $a.One + 1
    }
}

(0..2) | %{
    $b = @{
        One = 1
        Two = $b.One + 1
        Three = $b.Two + 1
    }
}
```

Make sure all calculations are idempotent, i.e. do not depend on a number of iterations.

Comment: An interesting solution - a bit weird but original :-)